# GREEDY Method for a matrix

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

I’m a bit confused regarding the following question:

Let $m,n \geqslant2$ be integers and $M=[1,2,....,m],N=[1,2,...,n]$. I’ve shown that the system $S=(E,J)$ is a matroid where $E=M$x$N$ (the set of cells of a rectangular matrix) and $I\in J$ if and only if $I$ is a set of cells where no three belong to the same column using the Exchange Proposition. I’ve then formulated the combinatorial optimisation problem associated with S. However, the part I’m struggling with is using GREEDY to solve the COP I formulated previously for the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 9 &  13& 3 &  12&2 \\ 
 10& 11 & 0 & 13 &1 \\ 
12 & 7 &1  & 9 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$$
The reason I’m confused is I know using GREEDY that I pick the most attractive cell i.e. $0$ and then I would reject all enteries in the same row and column and then repeat. Doing this I get, what I think is the optimal cost to be $9$. However I believe (I could be mistaken as we haven’t covered this method) that I could solve this by using something called the Hungarian method in which case the optimal cost is $38$. I’m just really confused if I’m being honest because I don’t understand how I use GREEDY to solve the COP problem formulated, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the problem to choose three cells, no two in the same row or column, of minimum sum?  Please state the problem in the question.

Comment: It can be solved by the Hungarian method, but 38 is the maximum sum, not the minimum.  If you amend your algorithm to choose the largest number instead of the smallest, you'll get 38, too.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry for the confusion as I don’t really understand your first post. The definition of a combinatorial optimisation problem that I’ve studied is that given a weight function, find an independent set that has biggest total weight. So what exactly is the COP associated with $S$? Because from that I would assume that I’m trying to find the maximum sum, but we’ve only ever been shown how to calculate the minumium sum, hence why I got $9$. So I’m not sure whether the COP I’ve formulated is correct.

Comment: What I’ve posted is all the information given in the question

Comment: Oh I think I’ve spotted my mistake. Of course it’s $38$. Thank you for the comment!!